# How to give name to the library file created by source?

Tags: makefile, cmake

In CMake my code is

```
add_library (Hell ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libsrc/src/square.cc)
```

It is creating library as `libHell.a` and I want to create `Hell.a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is affected by the [`PREFIX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/PREFIX.html) target property.  You can set the prefix to an empty string by using [`set_target_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/set_target_properties.html) somewhere after the `add_library` call:

```
set_target_properties(Hell PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```